# Can you run a portion of a script in parallel, based off the results of a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a portion of code which, when simplified, looks something like this:

```
select @mainlooptableid = min(uid)
    from queueofids with (nolock)
while (@mainlooptableid is not null)
begin
    -- A large block of code that does several things depending on the nature of @mainlooptableid
    -- .
    -- .
    -- .
    -- End of this blocks main logic
    delete from queueofids where uid = @mainlooptableid
    select @mainlooptableid = min(uid)
        from queueofids with (nolock)
end
```

I would like to be able to run the segment of code that's inside the while loop parallel for all uids inside the queueofids table. Based on what happens inside the loop **I can guarantee** that they will **not** interfere with each other in any way if they were to run concurrently, so logically it seems perfectly safe for it to run like this. The real question is if there is any way to get sql to run a portion of code for all values in there?

---

**NOTE:** I did think about generating a temp table with a series of created sql statements stored as strings, where each one is identical except for the @mainlooptableid value. But even if I have this table of sql statements ready to execute, I'm not sure how I would get all of these statements to execute concurrently.

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking.  Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how data would make this clearer? I just want to parallelise the statements that I execute inside the while loop (Besides those statements that keep the loop executing)...

Comment: What does that mean parallelise the statements?  sql-server is set based so do you need a while loop is the question.  This is why I am asking about sample data.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @JonH - The actual code I'm working with has about 800 lines of code inside the loop, with multiple branches all over the place. I can't show the actual code, and I don't see any good way of simplifying it down for an example. Who ever wrote this script originally just put a huge amount of logic here. I'm just trying to speed it up by running this in parallel.

Comment: Side note -- be careful throwing that nolock hint everywhere. It brings a lot more nasty thing to the table than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @Seb - Please see my comment.  If you want to do this you need to find a set based solution and rewrite the code from scratch.  You not being able to show us the code means we can't really help you.  But I am glad because I don't want to read 800 lines of t-sql code this morning.

Comment: @JonH - What do you mean by a set based solution? Do you know the link to any reference material that explains this in detail?

Comment: @Seb - What I mean is a lot of bad code is done because t-sql is fairly simple.  People start throwing in loops and cursors because they tackle it as if it were some client based c# application.  I am not saying your solution can be done in a set based way - because you cannot tell us what those 800 lines of code do.  What I am saying is there is a way to update / change data in a set based manner rather than looping but it really depends on your issue at hand.  Just google t-sql set based, here's an example: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/programming-sql-set-based-way

Comment: @JonH You are not going to turn 800 lines of code with branches all over the place into a set based command.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do this within a single SQL script; scripts are procedural.  If you want to explore this idea, you'd probably need to involve some form of multi-threaded application which would handle the looping aspect, and open a thread to hand off the parallelized portion of your current script.  Not impossible, but it does introduce some complexity.

If you want to do this all in SQL, then you'll have to rewrite the code to eliminate the loop.   As noted in the comments above, SQL Server is set-based, which means that it handles a certain amount of parallelization by doing work "all at once" against a set.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get SQL statements in the same script to run in parallel.

The closest thing to it is to try to create a set-based way of handling them, instead of running them in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that run in parallel will not necessarily make it faster if the threads are competing for the same resources.

I don't think SQL will parallelize statements.  But SQL will parallelize execution within a single statement.

Most programming frameworks have parallel. For example in .NET this would rather straight forward.  Create a procedure where you pass @mainlooptableid and just call it in parallel.